# In Appcelerator mobile SDK5.0.0.GA , Android App can't normal open

Tags: appcelerator

I have a question, I put the Titanium SDK by 4.0.0.GA Upgrade to 5.0.0.GA, build the android app, operation is this: after entering the app, press the back button to exit the app, and then click on the desktop icon, but stuck in Titanium welcome screen.Appc version is 5.5.0.Who know what's the problem?please.
(My English is not very good)

Comment: you upgraded to 5.0.0.GA or 5.5.0.GA?

Comment: @RenePot Yes ,do you know the problem

Comment: I do not. But which version is it? You talk about 2 different versions.

Comment: @RenePot I'm sorry, my description is not correct. I mean, in 5.0.0. GA, the above problems happened.

Comment: try updating to a newer version. 5.4.0.GA for example ;)

Comment: I have find the problem.
In the tiapp.xml file,changed the run - on - the main - thread has a value of false.
But still want to thank you for your answer@RenePot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the problem. In the tiapp.xml file,changed the run - on - the main - thread has a value of false.